# plan_table is old version fix results in ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I had the same quersion as reported [here](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plan_table_is_old_version.htm):

> Question:  I am getting this message when using "set autotrace on" for
> a query:
>
> ```
> - 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version
> ```
>
> How to I get the current plan table for my SQL explain plans?

The answer there is is very simple:

> You have to temporarily grant sysdba to the user and follow these
> steps:
>
> cd $ORACLE_HOME/RDBMS/ADMIN
>
> sqlplus system manager as sysdba
>
> grant sysdba to myuser;
>
> connect myuser as sysdba
>
> @catplan
>
> revoke sysdba from myuser;
>
> exit;
>
> This will prevent the old version of the plan table from being used.

But performing catplan.sql, at this command I got this error:

[image]

The whole catplan.sql is this:

```
Rem
Rem $Header: catplan.sql 02-feb-2008.21:10:57 kyagoub Exp $
Rem
Rem catplan.sql
Rem
Rem Copyright (c) 2003, 2008, Oracle. All rights reserved.  
Rem
Rem    NAME
Rem      catplan.sql - CATALOG create public plan table
Rem
Rem    DESCRIPTION
Rem      This script creates a public plan table as a global temporary
Rem      table accessible from any schema. It also creates the plan_id
Rem      sequence number.
Rem
Rem
Rem    MODIFIED   (MM/DD/YY)
Rem    kyagoub     02/02/08 - drop plan_table$ as it is not upgradedd
Rem    bdagevil    02/24/05 - increase maximum line size 
Rem    pbelknap    07/23/04 - type oid for stat_row_type 
Rem    pbelknap    06/30/04 - change oids 
Rem    kyagoub     06/23/04 - add sql_plan_stat_row_type 
Rem    pbelknap    06/25/04 - reserve toids 
Rem    kyagoub     04/27/04 - grant execute on sql_plan_xxx to public, create 
Rem                           public synonyms and move drop statements to 
Rem                           catnplan.sql 
Rem    pbelknap    04/20/04 - plan diff types 
Rem    bdagevil    05/08/04 - add other_xml column 
Rem    bdagevil    11/01/03 - all run dbms_xplan 
Rem    bdagevil    06/18/03 - rename hint alias to object_alias
Rem    bdagevil    06/06/03 - hint alias increased in size
Rem    aime        04/25/03 - aime_going_to_main
Rem    bdagevil    02/24/03 - bdagevil_sql_tune_5
Rem    bdagevil    02/13/03 - Created
Rem
  

create type dbms_xplan_type
  as object (plan_table_output varchar2(300));
/

create type dbms_xplan_type_table
  as table of dbms_xplan_type;
/

REM necessary for lower privileged users
grant execute on dbms_xplan_type to public;
grant execute on dbms_xplan_type_table to public;  
  
Rem
Rem Plan object type for plan diffs
Rem   - the sql_plan_table_type is a convenient way to store a handle on an
Rem     entire plan.  The dbms_xplan.compare_query_plans function takes in
Rem     two plans as arguments, so it needs a rolled-up type.  
Rem   - *** Note that these types are used by this function ONLY and should not
Rem         be used in user scripts/tables as they may be changed in the future
  
Rem
Rem SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE, SQL_PLAN_TABLE_TYPE
Rem
Rem  These types mirror the structure of the plan table and are used
Rem  to pass plans into this package for comparing plans.
Rem
Rem  You can populate a nested table of type SQL_PLAN_TABLE_TYPE as follows:
Rem
Rem  select CAST(COLLECT
Rem              (sql_plan_row_type(statement_id,plan_id,timestamp,remarks,
Rem               operation,options,object_node,object_owner,object_name,
Rem               object_alias,object_instance,object_type,optimizer,
Rem               search_columns,id,parent_id,depth,position,cost,
Rem               cardinality,bytes,other_tag,partition_start,
Rem               partition_stop,partition_id,NULL,distribution,cpu_cost,
Rem               io_cost,temp_space,access_predicates,filter_predicates,
Rem               projection,time,qblock_name,other_xml))
Rem         AS SQL_PLAN_TABLE_TYPE)
Rem  from plan_table where plan_id = :plid order by id;

create type sql_plan_row_type 
timestamp '1997-04-12:12:59:00' oid '00000000000000000000000000020210'
as object (
        statement_id       varchar2(30),
        plan_id            number,
        timestamp          date,
        remarks            varchar2(4000),
        operation          varchar2(30),
        options            varchar2(255),
        object_node        varchar2(128),
        object_owner       varchar2(30),
        object_name        varchar2(30),
        object_alias       varchar2(65),
        object_instance    numeric,
        object_type        varchar2(30),
        optimizer          varchar2(255),
        search_columns     number,
        id                 numeric,
        parent_id          numeric,
        depth              numeric,
        position           numeric,
        cost               numeric,
        cardinality        numeric,
        bytes              numeric,
        other_tag          varchar2(255),
        partition_start    varchar2(255),
        partition_stop     varchar2(255),
        partition_id       numeric,
        distribution       varchar2(30),
        cpu_cost           numeric,
        io_cost            numeric,
        temp_space         numeric,
        access_predicates  varchar2(4000),
        filter_predicates  varchar2(4000),
        projection         varchar2(4000),
        time               numeric,
        qblock_name        varchar2(30),
        other_xml          clob
) NOT FINAL
/
create or replace public synonym sql_plan_row_type for sql_plan_row_type
/
grant execute on sql_plan_row_type to public
/

Rem 
Rem sql_plan_table_type
Rem
create type sql_plan_table_type 
timestamp '1997-04-12:12:59:00' oid '00000000000000000000000000020211'
as table of sql_plan_row_type
/
create or replace public synonym sql_plan_table_type for sql_plan_table_type
/
grant execute on sql_plan_table_type to public
/

  
Rem
Rem ora_plan_id$: sequence number to uniquely identify explain plans
Rem 
create sequence ora_plan_id_seq$
  increment by 1
  start with 1
  minvalue 1
  maxvalue 4294967295
  cycle
  cache 10
/

Rem
Rem explain plan table
Rem NOTE: the plan table was not upgraded when the other_xml has been added
Rem       in 10.2. This means that upgraded databases to 10.2 or post 10.2
Rem       will not have this column which will invalid all packages and 
Rem       funtionalities which use the column.   
Rem       This is the main reason it is recreated in here. 
drop table plan_table$;
create global temporary table plan_table$
(
        statement_id       varchar2(30),
        plan_id            number,
        timestamp          date,
        remarks            varchar2(4000),
        operation          varchar2(30),
        options            varchar2(255),
        object_node        varchar2(128),
        object_owner       varchar2(30),
        object_name        varchar2(30),
        object_alias       varchar2(65),
        object_instance    numeric,
        object_type        varchar2(30),
        optimizer          varchar2(255),
        search_columns     number,
        id                 numeric,
        parent_id          numeric,
        depth              numeric,        
        position           numeric,
        cost               numeric,
        cardinality        numeric,
        bytes              numeric,
        other_tag          varchar2(255),
        partition_start    varchar2(255),
        partition_stop     varchar2(255),
        partition_id       numeric,
        other              long,
        other_xml          clob,
        distribution       varchar2(30),
        cpu_cost           numeric,
        io_cost            numeric,
        temp_space         numeric,
        access_predicates  varchar2(4000),
        filter_predicates  varchar2(4000),
        projection         varchar2(4000),
        time               numeric,
        qblock_name        varchar2(30)
) on commit preserve rows
/

Rem
Rem Add necessary privileges and make plan_table$ the default for 
Rem everyone
Rem
grant select, insert, update, delete on plan_table$ to public
/
create or replace public synonym plan_table for plan_table$
/

Rem
Rem SQL_PLAN_STAT_ROW_TYPE
Rem
Rem  This type is a sub-type of SQL_PLAN_ROW_TYPE. It is defined 
Rem  to capture the row source statistics associated to a plan. 
Rem
create type sql_plan_stat_row_type 
timestamp '1997-04-12:12:59:00' oid '00000000000000000000000000020212'
under sql_plan_row_type(
 executions     NUMBER,
 starts         NUMBER,
 output_rows    NUMBER,
 cr_buffer_gets NUMBER,
 cu_buffer_gets NUMBER,
 disk_reads     NUMBER,
 disk_writes    NUMBER,
 elapsed_time   NUMBER
)
/
create or replace public synonym sql_plan_stat_row_type for sql_plan_stat_row_type
/
grant execute on sql_plan_stat_row_type to public
/


Rem
Rem Load explain plan package
Rem
@@dbmsxpln.sql
@@prvtxpln.plb
```

My Oracle version is this:

> Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
> PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production CORE   10.2.0.4.0  Production TNS
> for 64-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production NLSRTL Version
> 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you post the whole CATPLAN.SQL? Screenshot displays just part of it.

Comment: Of course.  Done.

Comment: Also, which Oracle database version do you use? The last date in that script says "2008" which might be related to Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Littlefoot Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE 10.2.0.4.0 Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Thank you; have a look at code I posted below, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the 2nd line:

```
timestamp '1997-04-12:12:59:00' oid '00000000000000000000000000020210'
```

type gets created (tested on 10g):

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

Create type:

```
SQL> create type sql_plan_row_type
  2  --timestamp '1997-04-12:12:59:00' oid '00000000000000000000000000020210'
  3  as object (
  4          statement_id       varchar2(30),
  5          plan_id            number,
  6          timestamp          date,
  7          remarks            varchar2(4000),
  8          operation          varchar2(30),
  9          options            varchar2(255),
 10          object_node        varchar2(128),
 11          object_owner       varchar2(30),
 12          object_name        varchar2(30),
 13          object_alias       varchar2(65),
 14          object_instance    number,
 15          object_type        varchar2(30),
 16          optimizer          varchar2(255),
 17          search_columns     number,
 18          id                 number,
 19          parent_id          number,
 20          depth              number,
 21          position           number,
 22          cost               number,
 23          cardinality        number,
 24          bytes              number,
 25          other_tag          varchar2(255),
 26          partition_start    varchar2(255),
 27          partition_stop     varchar2(255),
 28          partition_id       number,
 29          distribution       varchar2(30),
 30          cpu_cost           number,
 31          io_cost            number,
 32          temp_space         number,
 33          access_predicates  varchar2(4000),
 34          filter_predicates  varchar2(4000),
 35          projection         varchar2(4000),
 36          time               number,
 37          qblock_name        varchar2(30),
 38          other_xml          clob
 39  ) NOT FINAL
 40  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

Try it, see how it behaves.

Comment: With this modification and similar modifications in two more places, catplan.sql has been executed (only with "already exists" errors) but 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)' result in this error:
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: package body "BIDAVIS2.DBMS_XPLAN" has errors

Comment: The errors are these: Line # = 766 Column # = 3 Error Text = PL/SQL: Item ignored
Line # = 775 Column # = 11 Error Text = PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_STATS_LIB' must be declared
Line # = 4539 Column # = 9 Error Text = PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line # = 4539 Column # = 39 Error Text = PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: DBMS_STATS_LIB is inaccessible to you (because you don't have privileges), or it doesn't exist (less likely, I'd say). Saying that you executed the whole CATPLAN.SQL, I presume it also executed the last two lines (@@dbmsxpln.sql and @@prvtxpln.plb)? The second one is supposed to create DBMS_XPLAN package. If it were successfully created, then you wouldn't get error saying that its package body has errors. Hm?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, at the end of the execution I got this error:  Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

Errors for PACKAGE BODY DBMS_XPLAN:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
766/3    PL/SQL: Item ignored
775/11   PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_STATS_LIB' must be declared
4539/9   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4539/39  PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Right; it is about DBMS_STATS_LIB. Have a look at package body and see what it does to DBMS_STATS_LIB (only SELECT? INSERT?). I don't have access to any DBA account at the moment so I can't try it myself, but - if you do (you should, according to information you posted, which requires you to connect as SYSTEM) - do it once again and try to GRANT qppropriate privileges to PUBLIC, e.g. GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON DBMS_STATS_LIB TO PUBLIC. Then run PRVTXPLN.PLB again.

Comment: It has only execute, debug privilegs. I granted them to public but the error remained.

Comment: I see; so that isn't even a table that is reported to be missing. OK, EXECUTE privilege should be enough, if it is executable. What is in line #4539? Which table is being referenced there?

Comment: This is a binary file (a wrapped package body), I don't see the lines. A big part of its content seems like a base64 code but I can't meaningfully decode it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any other idea :( As if there's mismatch between plan table, package that works with it, ... who knows what else. Sorry for not being able to assist any better. I hope someone else will help.

Comment: I managed to unwrap it and here is an error:   
PROCEDURE XPL_TRACE(
    MESSAGE IN VARCHAR2,
    FLAGS   IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1)
  IS
  EXTERNAL NAME "kdaptrc" WITH CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS(CONTEXT,
    FLAGS       OCINUMBER,      FLAGS           INDICATOR       SB4,
    MESSAGE     OCISTRING,      MESSAGE         INDICATOR       SB4
  )
  LIBRARY DBMS_STATS_LIB;

LINE/COL ERROR
---------------
259/3    PL/SQL: Item ignored
268/11   PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_STATS_LIB' must be declared
4032/9   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4032/39  PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Right; but we still don't know which table it is (at least, I don't see it).

Comment: The table is according to the line numbers is V$DATABASE,. But if I execute separately "SELECT DBID FROM V$DATABASE;" then it executes normally.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like the following: when you're granted access to some object **via role**, it works at SQL level or anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but does NOT work in named PL/SQL procedures (such as functions, **packages**, triggers, ...). Solution to that problem is to grant privileges **directly** to user, not via role.

Comment: Fine, thanks! I could grant every privilege to V$DATABASE, but DBMS_STATS_LIB still unavailable.  "grant execute on DBMS_STATS_LIB to BIDAVIS2" is not enough. How should I grant this?

Comment: While connected as BIDAVIS2 (presuming you have been granted CREATE SYNONYM privilege), try to do so: `create synonym dbms_stats_lib for sys.dbms_stats_lib;`

Comment: Wow! Oracle is a miracle! Now everything is executed, but for "SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY); " I got ERROR: an uncaught error in function display has happened; please contact Oracle support
       Please provide also a DMP file of the used plan table PLAN_TABLE
       ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BIDAVIS2.DBMS_XPLAN_TYPE_TABLE

3 rows selected.

Comment: I have a table PLAN_TABLE with 27 columns and a PLAN_TABLE$ with 36 columns in the BIDAVIS2 schema. Should I change PLAN_TABLE similar to PLAN_TABLE$?

Comment: "Contact Oracle support" won't help much as 10g is out of support. As I said, I still think that it is about mismatch of who-knows-what. Inconsistent datatypes ... as if plan table you created doesn't match what built-in package expects. You said you do use 10g, but - where did you obtain script that creates plan table? Does it belong to 10g as well?

Comment: Yes, probably. The header of catplan.sql is "02-feb-2008.21:10:57 kyagoub Exp $, " and prvtxpln.plb has date 08-08-2008, and most of the files in the RDBMS\ADMIN directory have this date. The exe and dll files in the BIN folder have also this creation date .